# Dynamic link parameters are not passed/received to the app when opened through Google Play Store

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-dynamic-links

My app is ionic-cordova based mobile app built for Android. Using dynamic links for sharing the app. When the user clicks the link on the mobiles where the app is installed:

1. it opens the app correctly and
2. the dynamic link parameters are passed to the app

but when the app is not installed on the mobile

1. it opens the google play store but
2. when user installs and launches the app the dynamic link parameters are either NOT passed to the app or NOT available to the app

Requesting the community help here.